# Oozie shell action doesn't send mail notification

Tags: shell, email, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am running a shell script through oozie. A piece of my shell script has below code. I receive an email when I run this shell script through unix Command line but when I run this shell script through oozie Job it will succeed but I dont get any mail. How can I resolve this? Or is there any alternative way I can get email with attachment once string matches in unix filesystem?

```
if [ "$Var" = "Error" ]
        then
                echo "Data error" | mail -v -s  "Data Error" -a error.csv -S smtp=smtp://mail-gateway -S from=localhost@gmail.com" Kevin@gmail.com
exit
```

Comment: Do you see an error message in the Yarn logs for that action? Did you check with your SysAdmin that `mail` (or `mailx`) is installed on all worker nodes? _(not present par default on CentOS, for instance)_

Comment: I tested and mail is working from all worker and master hosts.

Comment: Again, do you see an error message in the Yarn logs for that action? And did you test `mail` with that exact command line, when connected with the same exact Linux account that Oozie uses to run the job?